GridSearchCV runs smoothly when scoring='accuracy', but not when scoring=accuracy_score
When I run the following piece of code in a Jupyter notebook inside Visual Studio Code, it runs smoothly.
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=KNeighborsClassifier(),
                  param_grid=[{'n_neighbors': [3]}],
                  scoring='accuracy')
#                  scoring=accuracy_score)

gs.fit(X, y)

However, if I un-comment the commented line and comment the line above it, and re-run the notebook, I get the following error. Why?
c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:982: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 971, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test, **score_params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_param_validation.py", line 191, in wrapper
    params = func_sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\isc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 3267, in bind
    return self._bind(args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\isc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 3191, in _bind
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: too many positional arguments

  warnings.warn(
c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:982: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 971, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test, **score_params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_param_validation.py", line 191, in wrapper
    params = func_sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\isc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 3267, in bind
    return self._bind(args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\isc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 3191, in _bind
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: too many positional arguments

  warnings.warn(
c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:982: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 971, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test, **score_params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_param_validation.py", line 191, in wrapper
    params = func_sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\isc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 3267, in bind
    return self._bind(args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\isc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 3191, in _bind
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: too many positional arguments

  warnings.warn(
c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:982: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 971, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test, **score_params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_param_validation.py", line 191, in wrapper
    params = func_sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\isc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 3267, in bind
    return self._bind(args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\isc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 3191, in _bind
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: too many positional arguments

  warnings.warn(
c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:982: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 971, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test, **score_params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_param_validation.py", line 191, in wrapper
    params = func_sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\isc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 3267, in bind
    return self._bind(args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\isc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 3191, in _bind
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: too many positional arguments

  warnings.warn(
c:\Users\isc\Documents\Python\MLClassification\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:1052: UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [nan]
  warnings.warn(

